# if(this.isMounted()) not being called?

Tags: reactjs

Can you tell me why when I do this:

```
 var SomeComponent = React.createClass({

 getData: function(){

 if (this.isMounted()){

  var queryInfo = {
    userId: sessionStorage.getItem("user_id"),
    userRole: sessionStorage.getItem('user_role'),
    aptId : this.props.params
  }

  io = io.connect();
  io.emit('allTasks', queryInfo);
  io.on('allTasksInfo', function(data){
    reqwest({
      url: '/apartment/tasks/address',
      method: 'get',
      xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
      crossOrigin: true
    }).then(function(data){
       this.setState({
         dataSet: arr
       })
    }.bind(this));
   }.bind(this));
  }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    this.getData();
},

render: function(){...}

});
```

The code inside the if is executed, but I get the Uncaught Error: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

But when I do this:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({

getData: function(){

    var queryInfo = {
     userId: sessionStorage.getItem("user_id"),
     userRole: sessionStorage.getItem('user_role'),
     aptId : location.pathname.split("/")[4]
    }

    reqwest({
        url:'/operation/staff',
        method: 'get',
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        crossOrigin: true
    }).then(function(data){
        if(this.isMounted()){
            this.setState({
                operationStaff: data
            })
        }
    }.bind(this));
 }

 componentDidMount: function(){
   this.getData();
 },

 render: function(){...}

});
```

Everything is ok. Shouldn't the first just be executed when the component is mounted? What I am missing?

EDIT: I'm using react-router and express server with socket.io with server rendering (just the components, not the data - this I will fetch client side). After the answers, I can say:

- The component is not unmounting
- I can now tell that at first render, this warning doesn't appear even on second example:
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rbX9C6kejlbWVKeTZ6WVdGN0E/view?usp=sharing

But if I change the url and get back to this path (and here yes, the component unmounts off course), the *Ajax reqwest* is being called 2 times
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rbX9C6kejlUjFRYTBtejVLZGs/view?usp=sharing

This has something to do with the sockets implementation.

I will close this issue and open another regarding this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Without a complete example, we can only guess: At the moment the Ajax response is received, the component is already unmounted, thus calling `setState` on an unmounted component. Having the check in `getData` itself doesn't make a lot of sense if you call it from `componentDidMount` only. The condition will always be true.

Comment: I edited the question to include componentDidMount in second example. It was the same as first example, thats why the question.

Comment: I assumed that as well. But that's still not a complete example. I can't run the example. I don't know what makes the component mount or unmount. Hence only guesses.

Comment: If `isMounted` is never called, then can you remove the entire `if` body from your question, since it's never executed therefore isn't part of the problem?

Comment: Ok, but its a real example with real data fetching. Both options are working as it should, but with the first I get an a Uncaught Error.

Comment: @Chris Martin that is exactly the problem. The code inside the if is executed, but I get the Uncaught Error. I will update the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the first just be executed when the component is mounted?

Yes, and it is (what makes you think it is not?).

However, the *Ajax callback* itself is executed some time in the future and at that moment, the component may already be unmounted.

In the first example, the test is useless since the component is always mounted after `componentDidMount` was called. In the second example, you are testing whether the component is mounted just before you call `setState`, which makes more sense.

Here is a simplified example:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {name: 'foo'};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log('mounted...');

        setTimeout(function() {
            // this works fine
            console.log('updating state once...');
            this.setState({
                name: 'bar'
             });
        }.bind(this), 1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            // this will throw
            console.log('updating state twice...');
            this.setState({
                name: 'baz'
             });
        }.bind(this), 3000);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        console.log('unmounting...');
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>;
    }
});

React.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

setTimeout(function() {
    React.unmountComponentAtNode(
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
}, 2000);
```

If you run it you will notice that the second timeout will generate the same error because it is called after the component was unmounted:

Console output:

```
mounted...
updating state once...
unmounting...
updating state twice...
 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/pkzfbcr5/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its a promise, not a callback, and the component is still mounted, I dont change the url (I'm using react-router) nor do nothing to unmount the component. It's still there.

Comment: The function you pass to `.then` is still a callback. That's the only explanation (guess) I can come up with given the information you provided.  If that doesn't apply to your case you have to provide more information. However, I would still add a `console.log` in `componentWillUnmount` to be 100% certain that it does not unmount.

Comment: Yes, you are right it's a callback. The console.log proved that it doesn't unmount. My guess now is: something with the sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-router and express server with socket.io with server rendering (just the components, not the data - this I will fetch client side). After the answers, I can say:

- The component is not unmounting
- I can now tell that at first render, this warning doesn't appear even on second example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rbX9C6kejlbWVKeTZ6WVdGN0E/view?usp=sharing

But if I change the url and get back to this path (and here yes, the component unmounts off course), the Ajax reqwest is being called 2 times https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rbX9C6kejlUjFRYTBtejVLZGs/view?usp=sharing

This has something to do with the sockets implementation.

I will close this issue and open another regarding this. Thank you for the help.